# Auto complete box implemented using appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, autocomplete

I am developing an application using python version of appengine. I would like to implement a auto complete box in my application. The suggestions for the auto-complete options will be derived from a string property in my data model. Please help by providing an example of a similar implementation.

Comment: This isn't really a Python programming question. Your web page is in HTML and Javascript, so that's where you should be tagging and looking.

Comment: @Ken I disagree - the backend, to generate the autocomplete suggestions, will need to be in Python.

Comment: @user434541 You're probably getting downvoted because you're asking other people to write your code for you. It's more polite to ask for pointers and help in general than to expect other people to do your work. That said, I think it's a useful question to ask.

Answer (score 1):

- YUI-Django-AutoComplete
- YUI Autocomplete in Django snippet http://www.djangosnippets.org/users/pigletto/ pigletto
- Will Larson's http://lethain.com/entry/2007/dec/01/using-jquery-django-autocomplete-fields/ Using JQuery with Django for Autocomplete Fields
- http://www.djangosnippets.org/users/skam/ skam 's JQuery auto-complete widget in Django snippet http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/233/
- Jannis Leidel's http://jannisleidel.com/2008/11/autocomplete-form-widget-foreignkey-model-fields  An autocomplete form widget for ForeignKey model fields
- etc in http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AutoCompleteSolutions

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the jquery auto complete [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete)

**HTML :**

```
$("#search_users").autocomplete(URL);
```

**PYTHON:**

```
        q = (self.request.GET['q']).lower() 
        #query on model 
        for records in result:
            print records+"|"+records+"\n"
```